# add width to an element with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add width to some element in my HTML with js but it doesn't work Properly.
I want do that to in responsive design its scrolling.
I try to do that with this code but it doesn't work.
in responsive design every things commix.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {

        $('.seat-ready').click(function (e) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }

        });
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.chairs .row').each(function () {
            $(this).width(
                ($(this).children('a').length)
                *
                (
                    $(this).children('a').width() +
                    parseInt($(this).children('a').css("marginRight").replace('px', ''))
                    + parseInt($(this).children('a').css("marginLeft").replace('px', ''))
                )
                + $(this).attr('class').split('-')[1] * $(this).children('a').width()
            );
            $(this).width(
                 ($(this).children('span').length)
                 *
                 (
                     $(this).children('span').width() +
                     parseInt($(this).children('span').css("marginRight").replace('px', ''))
                     + parseInt($(this).children('span').css("marginLeft").replace('px', ''))
                 )
                 + $(this).attr('class').split('-')[1] * $(this).children('span').width()
             );
        });
        $('.chairs').each(function () {
            var rowLength = $(this).children('.row').length;
            for (var i = rowLength; i > rowLength - 12; i--) {
                $(this).children('.row').eq(i).addClass('top');
            }
        });
    }, 500);
</script>
```

```css
.hall-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.container-chairs {
  clear: both;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.text-center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.text-center #halls {
  display: none;
}

.header-hall-sections {
  font-family: 'Yekan';
  line-height: 230%;
  height: 220px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.header-hall-sections .header-hall-content {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 23px;
}
.header-hall-sections h2 {
  color: #9f3a67;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.header-hall-sections .date, .header-hall-sections .time {
  color: #9f3a67;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.header-hall-sections .btn.cancel-all {
  background: #dc3c3f;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 33px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 9px 25px 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.header-hall-sections .btn.cancel-all.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.header-hall-content .btn, .header-hall-content .btn + .btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 31px;
  padding: 7px 25px 0;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}
.header-hall-content .btn + .btn {
  margin-right: 103px;
  background: #009a35;
  border: 1px solid #328e4d;
  color: #fff;
}

.thumb-concert {
  margin-left: 15px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #c8c8c6;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 176px;
  width: 176px;
}

.header-hall {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  margin-top: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.header-hall:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.header-hall li {
  padding: 5px 33px 5px 0;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.header-hall li.seat-disabled {
  background: url('http://tik8.com/assets/user/img/chairs.png') no-repeat 100% -82px;
}
.header-hall li.seat-reserved {
  background: url('http://tik8.com/assets/user/img/chairs.png') no-repeat 100% -20px;
}
.header-hall li.seat-ready {
  background: url('http://tik8.com/assets/user/img/chairs.png') no-repeat 100% -51px;
}
.header-hall li.seat-selected {
  background: url('http://tik8.com/assets/user/img/chairs.png') no-repeat 100% -113px;
}
.header-hall li.seat-sold {
  background: url('http://tik8.com/assets/user/img/chairs.png') no-repeat 100% 11px;
}

.ticket-filed {
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #333;
}
.ticket-filed label {
  color: #111;
}

.chairs {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
}

.chairs .row {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.chairs .row span {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 21px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  cursor: default;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.chairs .row a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 21px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  cursor: default;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.chairs .row a.seat-ready, .chairs .row a.active {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.chairs .row span.seat-ready:hover, .chairs .row span.active:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.chairs .row span.seat-ready:hover .chairs-tooltip, .chairs .row span.active:hover .chairs-tooltip {
  font-weight: normal;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.chairs .row span.row-number {
  color: #444;
}
.row-name {
    font-size: 13px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 23px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
}
.chairs .row span input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 28px;
  height: 21px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: -1;
}

.chairs .row-number{
 z-index: 10;
}
.chairs .seat-disabled {
  background: url('http://tik8.com/assets/user/img/chair5.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  color: #e6e6e6;
}

.chairs .seat-reserved {
  background: url('http://tik8.com/assets/user/img/chair2.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  color: #666666;
}

.chairs .seat-ready {
  background: url('http://tik8.com/assets/user/img/chair4.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  color: white !important;
}
.chairs .seat-ready.active {
  background: url('http://tik8.com/assets/user/img/chair6.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  color: white;
}

.chairs .seat-sold {
  background: url('http://tik8.com/assets/user/img/chair1.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  color: gray;
}

.seat-ready > input[type="text"] {
    background-color: #6eab2b;
    border: medium none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 15px !important;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px !important;
     z-index: 100px;
}

a.seat-ready {
    background-color: #6eab2b;
    border: medium none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    /*width: 20px !important; */
  z-index: 100px;
}

.edit-label{
 padding: 0px;
}
.edit-label input[type="text"] {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 15px !important;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25px !important;
    z-index: 100px;
    color: black;
}
.seat-ready.active input[type="text"]{
 background-color: transparent;
 color: white;
}

a.seat-ready.active {
 background-color: transparent;
 color: white;
}

.left-1 {
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.left-2 {
  padding-right: 32px;
}

.left-3 {
  padding-right: 48px;
}

.left-4 {
  padding-right: 64px;
}

.left-5 {
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.left-6 {
  padding-right: 96px;
}

.left-7 {
  padding-right: 112px;
}

.left-8 {
  padding-right: 128px;
}

.left-9 {
  padding-right: 144px;
}

.left-10 {
  padding-right: 160px;
}

.left-11 {
  padding-right: 176px;
}

.left-12 {
  padding-right: 192px;
}

.chairs-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 190px;
  left: -81px;
  text-align: right;
  text-shadow: none;
  z-index: 99;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
.top .chairs-tooltip {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 135%;
}
.top .chairs-tooltip:after, .top .chairs-tooltip:before {
  bottom: auto;
  top: 100%;
}
.top .chairs-tooltip:after {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: white;
}
.top .chairs-tooltip:before {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: #d9d9d9;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------*\
 Nice Tooltip
\*--------------------------------------------------*/
#cvi_tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  color: #000;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 30px;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
#cvi_tooltip:after, #cvi_tooltip:before {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: solid transparent;
  top: 100%;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
#cvi_tooltip:after {
  border-top-color: white;
  border-width: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
}
#cvi_tooltip:before {
  border-top-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-width: 9px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -9px;
}
.right-1{
 padding-right:16px
}

.right-2{
 padding-right:32px
}

.right-3{
 padding-right:48px
}

.right-4{
 padding-right:64px
}

.right-5{
 padding-right:80px
}

.right-6{
 padding-right:96px
}

.right-7{
 padding-right:112px
}

.right-8{
 padding-right:128px
}

.right-9{
 padding-right:144px
}

.right-10{
 padding-right:160px
}

.right-11{
 padding-right:176px
}

.right-12{
 padding-right:192px
}
.content {
   position: relative;
}
.top {
position: static;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hall-wrap">
    <section class="container-chairs">
        <section class="content">
            <div class="chairs">
                <div class="row right-2">
                    <span class="row-number">1</span>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">1</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">2</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">3</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">4</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">5</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">6</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">7</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">8</a>
                    <span class="offset"></span>
                    <span class="offset"></span>
                    <span class="row-number">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row right-1">
                    <span class="row-number">2</span>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">1</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">2</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">3</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">4</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">5</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">6</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">7</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">8</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">9</a>
                    <span class="offset"></span>
                    <span class="row-number">2</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row right-2">
                    <span class="row-number">3</span>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">1</a>
                    <span class="seat-sold">2</span>
                    <span class="seat-sold">3</span>
                    <span class="seat-sold">4</span>
                    <span class="seat-sold">5</span>
                    <span class="seat-sold">6</span>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">7</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">8</a>
                    <span class="offset"></span>
                    <span class="offset"></span>
                    <span class="row-number">3</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row right-2">
                    <span class="row-number">4</span>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">1</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">2</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">3</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">4</a>
                    <span class="seat-disabled">5</span>
                    <span class="seat-disabled">6</span>
                    <span class="seat-disabled">7</span>
                    <span class="seat-disabled">8</span>
                    <span class="seat-disabled">9</span>
                    <span class="offset"></span>
                    <span class="row-number">4</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row right-2">
                    <span class="row-number">5</span>
                    <a href="">1</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">2</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">3</a>
                    <span class="seat-disabled">4</span>
                    <span class="seat-disabled">5</span>
                    <span class="seat-disabled">6</span>
                    <span class="seat-disabled">7</span>
                    <span class="seat-disabled">8</span>
                    <span class="offset"></span>
                    <span class="offset"></span>
                    <span class="row-number">5</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row right-1">
                    <span class="row-number">6</span>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">1</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">2</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">3</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">4</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">5</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">6</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">7</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">8</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">9</a>
                    <span class="offset"></span>
                    <span class="row-number">6</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row right-2">
                    <span class="row-number">7</span>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">1</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">2</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">3</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">4</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">5</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">6</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">7</a>
                    <a href="" class="seat-ready">8</a>
                    <span class="offset"></span>
                    <span class="offset"></span>
                    <span class="row-number">7</span>
                </div>
        </section>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Very complicated question you have... Do you want add width to "seating" divs?

Comment: Could you maybe tell what your overall goal is? How should the result look like? maybe provide some picturres with start and end state, because in many cases you can achieve a really good responsive design via css media queries.

Comment: You are doing lots of coding of JQuery. i think it is not needed there.

Comment: Please remove irrelevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'll take a guess what you are looking for. Maybe its something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7t1m7vpa/3/).

Note: The js is only for generating the html, which is very similar to what you used.

```js
var HALL_DATA = [
  /* 0=offset, 1=ready, 2=sold, 3=disabled */
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0], //1
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0], //2
  [1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0], //3
  [1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,0], //4
  [1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,0,0], //5
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0], //6
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]  //7
  
 ];
 var SEAT_CLASSES = ['offset', 'seat-ready', 'seat-sold', 'seat-disabled'];
 var seatTemplate = '<a href="#" class="{SEAT_CLASS}">{SEAT_NR}</a>';
 var rowTemplate = '<div id="row-{ROW_NR}" class="row">{ROW_CONTENT}</div>';

 function getHallContent() {
  var html = '';
  for(i=0; i<HALL_DATA.length; i++) {
   html += rowTemplate.replace('{ROW_CONTENT}',getRowContent(i)).replace('{ROW_NR}',i+1);
   console.log()
  }
  return html;
 }
 function getRowContent(theIndex) {
  rowHtml = '';
  rowData = HALL_DATA[theIndex];
  for(j=0; j<rowData.length; j++) {
   var seatClass = SEAT_CLASSES[rowData[j]],
    seatNr = j+1; //cause j is index
   rowHtml += seatTemplate.replace('{SEAT_CLASS}',seatClass).replace('{SEAT_NR}',seatNr);
  }
  return rowHtml;
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hall-wrap').html(getHallContent());        
 });
```

```css
.hall-wrap {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    max-width:200px;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.row a {
    display:table-cell;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:20px;
}
.seat-ready {
    background: #89CC45;
}
.seat-sold {
    background: #C93E41;
}
.seat-disabled {
    background: #C2C5CF;
}
a.offset {
    background:transparent;
    color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hall-wrap"></div>
```